# Running project on iPhone crashes but it works on the simulator

Tags: ios, swift

This is the error that I get and I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSAuthCore.framework/AWSAuthCore
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/989872E5-F2E1-4360-97B6-5995192BA95A/Project.app/Project
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/989872E5-F2E1-4360-97B6-5995192BA95A/Project.app/Frameworks/AWSAuthCore.framework/AWSAuthCore:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/989872E5-F2E1-4360-97B6-5995192BA95A/Project.app/Frameworks/AWSAuthCore.framework/AWSAuthCore'

Comment: Thanks for posting! Would you mind sharing some more context? from what you have here it looks like a library may not be included in your deployment on your iPhone but it's tough to say as is.

Answer (score 0):

In the target's **General tab**, under the `Embedded Binaries` field add the `AWSAuthCore` framework to resolve the crash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Podfile comment the line of **use_frameworks!** like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
```

And add **use_modular_headers!**

Then do this in your terminal:

1. pod update
2. pod install

Unfortunately, Apple decided to prevent using cocoapods if your account is free.

Comment: I've tried this but I then get this error "framework not found AWSAuthCore" 

This is my current Podfile: 
"platform :ios, '9.0'

target :'Project' do
 #use_frameworks!
 use_modular_headers!

 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
   pod 'AWSAuthCore', '~> 2.6.1'
   pod 'AWSDynamoDB', '~> 2.6.5'
end"

Comment: If the error for AWSAuthCore pod try to uninstall it and build your app on your phone, if it works then try to update cocoapods then pod update